# Opening a date picker automatically when a page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm writing a mobile app based on `html`, `css` and `javascript`. I need to open a date picker automatically when a page loads in mobile. How can I do it?

Comment: can you post relevant code?

Comment: In case you init the picker you can use: $('YourSelector').datepicker("show");

Answer (score 3):

You need to wait for *onload* event and then call the open function for you date picker. Without knowing about whether you use jQuery or some other framework for date picker, it is hard to give more concrete instructions.

For [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) it looks something like this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    // Open date picker
});
```

In case of not using jQuery and vanilla JS instead, refer to [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp)

```
document.onload = function() {
    // Open date picker
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to trigger it using jQuery's `ready` event. Judging from your tags, this should work. `.datepicker-element` is the selector for the element with the datepicker.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.datepicker-element').datepicker( "show" );
});
```

Comment: I used: `$('#IdTag').datetimepicker("show");`